# ClickOnce Hosting Requirements?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I would like to publish my app to a website so users can download via a URL and the app can update from the same location.

I have 'standard' Linux hosting, but I get the message when trying to publish with ClickOnce: **The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed.**

Is Windows (ASP.NET?) hosting required for this to work? If the app is running as a desktop app I thought Linux hosting would be okay.

Thanks in advance for any clarification on this!

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio will try to use the FrontPage Server Extensions if you specify an http URI as your "Publishing Folder Location". If you're publishing to a server without FPSE support, use an ftp URI (or a UNC path if you have direct access to the server) instead.

I've always used ftp to deploy my Internet-hosted ClickOnce apps and it works a treat.

You can specify the "Installation folder URL" as an http URI - just make sure you use ftp for the publishing location.

Comment: A variation on this is to use a localhost URL as your Publishing Folder Location, and then to transfer the files by a more traditional means from that local directory.  That can be useful if you need to control the time of release; we usually build the release during business hours and transfer everything *but* the updated manifest across to the update server, then push the manifest over after West Coast business hours.

If you're deploying a .NET 2.0 application, don't forget to specify the Installation Folder URL as the "Update location" as well in the Updates dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The Frontpage server extensions are only required for the ClickOnce publishing from Visual Studio to work. As far as I am aware, most of the click once magic occurs in the browser.

See [this article](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0611041) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You could publish to your local machnine, then run mage on the manifest and change the install location to your web site uri and finally manually copy the files to your server.

Not the most automated solution in the world, but it would work.